# How to secure Infinispan cluster

Tags: authentication, cluster-computing, infinispan, jgroups

I am trying to prepare a secure Infinispan cluster using SimpleToken as described in here [JGroup](http://jgroups.org/manual/html/protlist.html#CommonProps) . Although I provided the required configuration, new nodes are able to join the cluster even if they have different 'auth_value' value.

Here is my configuration for the first node:

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/JGroups-3.6.xsd">
```

```
    ....
    ....

    <AUTH auth_class="org.jgroups.auth.SimpleToken" auth_value="cluster1"/>
</config>
```

for the second node, I am using the same configuration with different auth_value:

```
<AUTH auth_class="org.jgroups.auth.SimpleToken" auth_value="cluster2"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came that the order of configuration nodes in JGroup xml file is important. Base one RedHat support team [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2360521)

> For Asymmetric encryption (A shared keystore is not required):
>   1) Configure the jgroups subsystem:
>
> 1. ASYM_ENCRYPT should be configured immediately before NAKACK, and AUTH should be immediately before GMS.
> 2. Note that the other protocols shown here for context will differ slightly depending on the JGroups version.

Which means my JGroup file should looks like the following :

```
<AUTH auth_class="org.jgroups.auth.SimpleToken" auth_value="cluster1"/>
<pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="false"join_timeout="15000"/>
```

Now, when I start the second node which has auth_value="cluster2" I receive the following warnings and errors :

node 1:

```
[WARN] AUTH: failed to validate AuthHeader token from xxxx, token: auth_value=cluster1
```

node 2:

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: authentication failed
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.ClientGmsImpl.isJoinResponseValid(ClientGmsImpl.java:188)
    at

Answer (score 0):

Note that the latest version of ASYM_ENCRYPT does not require AUTH anymore; if you use a certificate based key exchange such as SSL_KEY_EXCHANGE. Details can be found at [1].

The previous answer is correct: the order of protocols matter much.

[1] http://www.jgroups.org/manual4/index.html#Security